# Simulate Camera in Numpy

Tags: numpy, noise

I have the task to simulate a camera with a full well capacity of 10.000 Photons per sensor element 
in numpy. My first Idea was to do it like that:

```
camera = np.random.normal(0.0,1/10000,np.shape(img))
Imgwithnoise= img+camera
```

but it hardly shows an effect. 
Has someone an idea how to do it?

Comment: Does that mean that no signal greater than 10,000 will be recorded? Also `1/10,000` scale means the noise you are adding to your image is very small, so you likely won't see any difference in `Imgwithnoise` depending on their values. It would help if you could provide some numbers for `img` etc, and more fully explain your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well the problem is that im not sure myself about the output. I guess that 10.000 could mean no greater signal, yes, but I dont know what that means and how to imply it with regard of noise...

Answer (score 0):

From what I interpret from your question, if each physical pixel of the sensor has a 10,000 photon limit, this points to the *brightest* a digital pixel can be on your image. Similarly, 0 incident photons make the darkest pixels of the image.

You have to create a map from the physical sensor to the digital image. For the sake of simplicity, let's say we work with a **grayscale** image.
Your first task is to fix the colour bit-depth of the image. That is to say, is your image an 8-bit colour image? (Which usually is the case) If so, the brightest pixel has a *brightness value* = 255 (= 2<sup>8</sup> - 1, for 8 bits.) The darkest pixel is always chosen to have a value 0.

So you'd have to map from the range `0 --> 10,000` (sensor) to `0 --> 255` (image). The most natural idea would be to do a linear map (i.e. every pixel of the image is obtained by the same multiplicative factor from every pixel of the sensor), but to correctly interpret (according to the human eye) the brightness produced by `n` incident photons, often different *transfer functions* are used.
A *transfer function* in a simplified version is just a mathematical function doing this map - logarithmic TFs are quite common.

Also, since it seems like you're generating noise, it is unwise and conceptually wrong to add `camera` itself to the image `img`. What you should do, is fix a *noise threshold* first - this can correspond to the *maximum number of photons that can affect a pixel reading* as the maximum noise value. Then you generate random numbers (according to some distribution, if so required) in the range `0 --> noise_threshold`. Finally, you use the map created earlier to add this noise to the image array.

Hope this helps and is in tune with what you wish to do. Cheers!